# background music automatically stops

Tags: java, android

I have made an application with Splash Music. But whenever I go in preferences of app, the music automatically stops, and then never plays untill I restart the application. Same is the case when I open an activity, which tells whether phone is in "Normal" or in "Silent" Mode.

- What is the reason for this weird behavior?
  Here is the Splash music code where I check whether to play music or not..

  public class SplashScreen extends Activity{

  ```
  MediaPlayer mp;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);

      mp= MediaPlayer.create(SplashScreen.this, R.raw.got);
      SharedPreferences pref= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
  ;
  if(pref.getBoolean("music", true))
  {
      mp.start();
  }
  if(pref.getBoolean("loop", true))
  {
      mp.setLooping(true);
  }
  Thread timer= new Thread()
  {
      public void run()
      {
      try
      {
          sleep(5000);
          Class ourclass = Class.forName("com.umer.practice2.Menu");
          Intent myintent= new Intent(SplashScreen.this,ourclass);
          startActivity(myintent);
      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
      }
        };
      timer.start();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      super.onPause();
      finish();
  }
  ```

  }

Thanks

Comment: It would be much better if you show your code. There're many ways to implement your functionality

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are creating and playing your mediaplayer object on the main thread. When your activity is getting paused, you are finishing the activity which is stopping your mediaplayer. If you want to keep you music independent of the activity, offshore it to a service.

Answer (score 0):

Running in a Service should help you.

Comment: You don't say anything that the existing answer did not already say.